# Swift: SKNode `contains(_:)` not always working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am having trouble with `contains(_:)` to check if an `SKSpriteNode` contains a point. Specifically a point from `UIPanGestureRecognizer.location(in:)`.

Drawing two boxes (red and green) on the screen as `SKSpriteNodes`, another node (colored yellow) is added and will be dragged across the scene using an `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

The result of `contains(_:)` seems to depend on the parent of the node that is being dragged, which I don't expect. It should simply check if a specific `CGPoint` lies inside of the coordinates of a node.

```
    var box1: SKSpriteNode?
    var box2: SKSpriteNode?
    var draggingNode: SKSpriteNode?

    box1 = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    box1?.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    addChild(box1!)

    box2 = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    box2?.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    addChild(box2!)
        
    draggingNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 25, height:25))
    box1!.addChild(draggingNode!)
```

As seen above, the yellow `draggingNode` is a child of the red node `box1`.

Here is the gesture recogniser code that moves the `draggingNode` and print outs the results of the test:

```
    @objc func panned(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let pointInView: CGPoint = sender.location(in: view)
        let pointInScene = convertPoint(fromView: pointInView)

        if sender.state == .changed {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
            draggingNode?.position.x += translation.x
            draggingNode?.position.y -= translation.y
            sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)

            print("is in box1: ", box1!.contains(pointInScene))
            print("is in box2: ", box2!.contains(pointInScene))
        }
```

- The expected result is that `box1!.contains(pointInScene)` only returns `true` if the `draggingNode` is actually above `box1`.
- The actual result is that `box1!.contains(pointInScene)` always returns `true`, no matter if the `draggingNode` is dragged above `box1` or not.

For `box2`, of which the `draggingNode` is not a child, the results are correct.

- If I add the `draggingNode` as a child of `box2`, the results are reversed: `box2!.contains(pointInScene)` now always returns `true` and `box1!.contains(pointInScene)` works correctly.
- If I add the `draggingNode` as a child of the `SKScene` itself, everything works as expected.

Question: Why is the parent of `draggingNode` influencing the result of `contains(_:)`, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that if you add a child node to a parent they effectively create a two node system. and this affects the frame size. if you look at `box1?.calculateAccumulatedFrame()` you will see that box1's frame expands to include wherever the yellow draggingNode position is.

you are getting strange results because yellow is effectively doing a hit test against a rectangle that *it's own position* is helping to define.

solution: add both box1 and draggingNode to a third parent node (let's call it "container"). then box1's accumulated frame will not vary during the pan gesture, and your hit tests will be accurate.